# Elasticsearch document mapping type is different as stored type

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, mapping

Hi I have an index in Elasticsearch 2 which contains this definition of property contacts:

```
...
,
"contacts": {
   "properties": {
        "domains": {
             "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
         },
         "emails": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
         },
         "phones": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
         }
    }
},
...
```

and as I see data in this index for contacts property contains arrays istead of string as mapping says. How is it possible?

```
    "contacts": {
        "domains": [
            "http://www.xxxxx.sk",
            "http://www.sssss.sk",
            "http://ddddd.sk",
            "http://www.ddddd.sk",
            "http://www.wwwww.sk",
            "http://www.ffffffff.sk"
        ],
        "phones": [
            "123456789",
            "987456321",
            "852147963"
        ],
        "emails": [
            "ccc@cccccc.sk",
            "ggggggg@vggggg.sk",
            "qqqqqqq@qqqqq.sk",
            "sssssssss@sssss.sk",
            "nadacia@volkswagen.sk",
            "vvvvvv@vvvvvvv.sk",
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ES documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

> In Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated `array` type. Any field can
>   contain zero or more values by default, however, all values in the
>   array must be of the same datatype.

Comment: I'll add that if you start using [phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html) queries, it's useful to know that Elasticsearch has a parameter called [position_increment_gap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/position-increment-gap.html) that helps Elasticsearch understand that those array entries are in fact separate.

What this means is that even with `phrase` queries, having these multiple entries in an array _should_ generally work well.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to query if exists the contacts.emails property in ES6? I tried 
```"query": {"exists": {"field": "contacts.emails"}}``` but it returns empty result. i am sure there are some data....